# JQuery Script not being read in by HTML

Tags: php, jquery, alert

My JQuery code is not working. I tried functions such as "mouseenter" and that didn't work, so I simply tried this and the alert does not show up. Is it a problem with the syntax or possibly something I am missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

The JS is this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("JQuery is working! :D");
    });
```

EDIT:

scr -> src
However, this has not solved the problem.

I am using Chrome v. 26 on Mac OSX 10.7.5

This is the console error: 
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Try opening the JavaScript console (in IE or Chrome, press F12) and look for JavaScript errors.

Comment: Are you using an old version of IE?  Less than IE9?  Because jQuery 2.0 doesn't support IE6, 7, or 8... just an idea

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 26 on Macintosh OSX 10.7.5

Comment: is there any error in the console?

Comment: this is the console error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

has "src" misspelled.

It should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

As a result, jQuery is not loading.

When diagnosing this type of issue, it is useful to open the JavaScript console.  In IE or Chrome, press F12 then select the JavaScript tab.  You would probably see an error along the lines of "$ is not defined".

Comment: Thanks, a pretty glaring error, I suppose (I am quite new to JS), but that does not seem to have fixed the problem. The alert still does not show up. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you open the JavaScript console and look for error messages?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: It should give you a line number.  Does that line number correspond to the code that you posted?  If so which line?  If not, post code surrounding the line where the error is shown.  If you have a syntax error within the `<script>` tag, it may cause all of the JavaScript in the tag to not run (depending on the exact error).